# Standalone Python interpreter

Tags: python, operating-system

I want to run a python program without any underlying OS.

I have read articles on running python on small microcontrollers, but i want it on a bigger processor (Intel, ARM).

My criteria is:

1. It could be directly run as binary.
2. The Python interpreter could be loaded, onto which I can run my program.
3. At worst, tell me an extremely small, basic OS i can run it on.

Note: I want to use my program like a minimalistic operating system. I should be able to load it like any other OS, and it should be able to access memory and have basic I/O.

Note 2: Will there be limitations in terms of python's functions?

Comment: See https://wiki.python.org/moin/EmbeddedPython.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** this post describes x86 exclusively, as, next to ARM, requested by the OP.

> It could be directly run as binary.

Binary? Python is not compiled, so no binary is produced. I think you mean just "run a Python program directly" here.
You could implement an additional compilation step, so that Python source files are compiled to [bytecode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) prior to being executed, of course.

> The Python interpreter could be loaded, onto which I can run my program.

"loaded" is a problem here. You need software to load the interpreter, displaying a chicken-egg problem. Intel x86 solves the problem by using a so-called [BIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS) (Basic I/O System), which starts further, user-defined programs. This "user-defined" program would be your Python interpreter then.
On more modern machines, [UEFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) is used instead of the legacy BIOS.

> I want to use my program like a minimalistic operating system. I
>   should be able to load it like any other OS, and it should be able to
>   access memory and have basic I/O.

The aforementioned BIOS provides, as the acronym says, basic I/O functionality like reading/writing from/to disks, reading/writing from/to the screen, etc. Either use these basic routines and abstract from these or circumvent them and rewrite them all from scratch. That includes graphics drivers (a basic VGA driver will suffice), disk drivers (for loading Python files from disk), and filesystem (a simple FAT-16 is sufficient).
After all, you not only need to write a Python interpreter but a whole development environment from scratch.

> Will there be limitations in terms of python's functions?

It depends on what you implement. For networking you need the appropriate drivers, for file stuff a filesystem + secondary storage driver. You are the ultimate master of your system you create, so it is up to you how un/limited your Python environment will be.

Comment: I know that python is interpreted not compiled. What i meant by 'run as binary' was if compilers were available for python. I have seaerched, haven't found much.

Comment: @UditDey I don't know one either. I only know about Python bytecode.

Comment: Even if i compile my code to Python bytecode, i can't run it directly, can I? Because the Python bytecode instruction set is not the same as x86's. So it won't be helpful

Comment: @UditDey That's where the interpreter comes into play and interprets the bytecode and executes it in native x86 instructions. The actual interpreter only converts between bytecode and x86 instructions on your implementation. Some Python "compiler" reduces the source code to bytecode. You can cut out this detour, of course.

Comment: So i will nevertheless have to run the interpreter directly

Comment: @UditDey "directly"? What does "**in**directly" mean, then?

Comment: "indirectly" would mean with underlying OS

Comment: @UditDey What no, of course you don't have to. You can run it directly (with no OS, as described in my answer) and indirectly (with an underlying OS).

Comment: Thx for clarification, it would be helpful if you could redirect me to a site or article that could guide me to how i can run it directly

Comment: @UditDey I'm sorry but that's off-topic and belongs to your tasks as the OP. If my answer didn't answer your question, I'll rewrite it or delete it. But answers are supposed to help you, not hyperlinks.